# Marshalling nested classes with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to marshal some classes I designed, with standard JAXB, the classes all have void constructors, this is my first attempt at using JAXB or marshalling/unmarhslling in any language for that matter but as I understand it JAXB should be able to marshall them without a XSD.

The classes are as follow:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="place")
class Place {
    @XmlAttribute
    //various fields and get set methods
    public Place() {          
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name="Arc")
class Arc {
    // various fields and get set methods
    @XmlAttribute
    Place p;
    public setPlace(Place p) {
        // ...
    }

    public Arc() { 
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name="Transition")
class Transition {
   Arc[] a;

   public Transition() {        
   }
}
```

I can marshall the `Place` class but not the `Arc` class, the `Transition` I didn't even try, the classes have the `@XMLPropriety` tags but when it reaches the nested `Place` class JAXB doesn't seem to understand which XML object to map it too.

If there is another tag I should be using for the nested class or there's another error I'm overlooking?

Comment: Please put the real code you use into your question. The JAXB annotations are *very* imporant to understand your question.

Comment: I will as soon as I can access it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing special you need to do to handle nested classes with any [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation.  Below is a complete example where only one `@XmlRootElement` annotation is used:

**Transition**

```
package forum13159089;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
class Transition {

    Arc[] a;

    public Arc[] getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(Arc[] a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

}
```

**Arc**

```
package forum13159089;

class Arc {

    Place p;

    public Place getPlace() {
        return p;
    }

    public void setPlace(Place p) {
        this.p = p;
    }

}
```

**Place**

```
package forum13159089;

class Place {

}
```

**Demo**

```
package forum13159089;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Transition.class);
        
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum13159089/input.xml");
        Transition transition = (Transition) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
        
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(transition, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<transition>
    <a>
        <place/>
    </a>
    <a>
        <place/>
    </a>
</transition>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted

---

**Note:** `@XMLProperty` is not a JAXB annotation.

Answer (score 5):

This code is working for me. Please check.

```
 @XmlRootElement
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class First {

        @XmlElement
        private String name;
        @XmlElement
        private String surname;
        @XmlElement
        private String address;
            getters and setters
    }


    @XmlRootElement
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class Second {

        @XmlElement
        private String address1;
        @XmlElement
        private String address2;
        @XmlElement
        private String address3;
        @XmlElement
        private First first;
            getters and setters
    }

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Forth {

    @XmlElement
    private String address6;
    @XmlElement
    private String address7;
    @XmlElement
    private Second[] array = new Second[2];
        getters and setters
}

    public static void main(String arsg[]) throws Exception 
        {
            First first =  new First();
        first.setName("Kshitij");
        first.setSurname("Solanki");
        first.setAddress("Nadiad");

        Second second = new Second();
        second.setAddress1("Kshiutij_1");
        second.setAddress2("Kshiutij_2");
        second.setAddress3("Kshiutij_3");
        second.setFirst(first);

        Second second1 = new Second();
        second1.setAddress1("Kshiutij_1");
        second1.setAddress2("Kshiutij_2");
        second1.setAddress3("Kshiutij_3");
        second1.setFirst(first);

        Second[] arra = {second, second1};

        Forth forth = new Forth();
        forth.setAddress6("kjhgaksjfsadf");
        forth.setAddress7("sdlkfsdf");
        forth.setArray(arra);

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Forth.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        marshaller.marshal(forth, stringWriter);
        System.out.println(stringWriter.toString());
        }
```

Sorry if I didn't understood your problem.

Comment: Your classes are *very* different from the classes in the question. You don't have a `Arc[]` member, for example.

Comment: Well I didn't declare the nested class as static in the first place I can't access the code right now, I'll get back to you as soon as possible.

Comment: +1 - BTW since JAXB is configuration by exception you only need to add annotations where you want the XML representation to be different from the default (i.e. since all fields/properties are treated as `@XmlElement` you only need to use that annotation when you want to specify a non-default element name.  Also `@XmlRootElement` is only required on the root object.  The following should help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html

Comment: Thank you this is a very fine answer, but I chose the one below because I'm really new to JAXB, once I get more experience I will try it with this more elegant style.